# Thymleaf Template not being used properly within spring boot

Tags: spring-security, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm having trouble to set up properly my spring boot application.

Basically I have this pom.xml :

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath />
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-hateoas</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

and this web app configuration :

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("security/login");
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

@Bean
public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();

    Set<IDialect> dialects = new HashSet<IDialect>();
    dialects.add(springSecurityDialect());

    templateEngine.setAdditionalDialects(dialects);
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return templateEngine;
}

@Bean
public SpringSecurityDialect springSecurityDialect() {
    SpringSecurityDialect dialect = new SpringSecurityDialect();
    return dialect;
}

@Bean
public TemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
    //resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return resolver;
}
}
```

On the ressources side I've the following :

```
/src
--/main
----/resources
------/template
--------/home
----------/home.html
--------/security
----------/login.html
```

I also have this one class :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/home").permitAll()
            .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")
                .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
            .and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
            .and()
                .exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403")
            .and()
                .csrf();
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth
        .jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource())
            .usersByUsernameQuery("select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
            .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from user_roles where username=?");

    ;
}

}
```

And no matter what, I can't fix nor understand the following error :

```
2016-08-19 11:40:58.707 ERROR 6874 --- [nio-8080-exec-1]         org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1]       Exception processing template "home/home": Error resolving template "home/home",  template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured   Template Resolvers
2016-08-19 11:40:58.723 ERROR 6874 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet]      : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [/fidzit] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home/home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers] with root cause
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home/home", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateRepository.getTemplate(TemplateRepository.java:246) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1104) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1060) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1011) ~[thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at 
[...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to choose the proper name for your templates directory: `template` or `templates`.

Look here:

```
resolver.setPrefix("templates/");
```

and here:

```
/src
--/main
----/resources
------/template
```